# Clearing contents of TextField JavaFX

Tags: javafx, textfield

I have a problem with clearing the TextField using setText(" ") method.
I'm trying to check if specific value can be entered in tile and if it can't be then I just want to set it to blank space. It actually works if I put any other value there so I think its not the logic problem? It only doesn't work if I want to set it to blank space.

**Tile class**

That is the class where the problem takes place.

```
package com.company;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

import static com.company.Game.TILE_SIZE;

public class Tile extends StackPane {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private static int[][] tab = new int[][]
            {
                    {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8},
                    {0, 0, 10, 0, 7, 0, 0},
                    {0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0},
                    {0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0},
                    {0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 6}
            };
    private Utility utility = new Utility();

    private Rectangle border = new Rectangle(TILE_SIZE - 8, TILE_SIZE - 8);
    public TextField text = new TextField();


    public Tile(int x, int y) {
        Utility utility= new Utility();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;


        border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        text.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: black;" +
                "-fx-control-inner-background: green;"
                +"-fx-display-caret: false;");
        text.setTextFormatter (new TextFormatter<Integer>(c -> {
            if (c.getControlNewText().matches("^\\d{1,2}")) {
                return c ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        }));


        text.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldValue, newValue) ->
        {
            if (!newValue) {
                if (text.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    String cos = text.getText();
                    int cos2 = Integer.parseInt(cos);
                    if(utility.isWon(tab))
                    {
                        Platform.exit();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!utility.isMoveValid(tab, this.y, this.x, cos2))
                        {
                            text.setText(""); //it works if it's not a blank string

                        } else {
                            tab[this.y][this.x] = cos2;

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        text.setFont(Font.font(50));

        getChildren().addAll(border, text);
        setTranslateX(this.x*TILE_SIZE);
        setTranslateY(this.y*TILE_SIZE);

    }


}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] (minimal, complete program that can be copy and pasted to reproduce the issue without any change).

Comment: Don’t look at awt based solutions if you are using JavaFX.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, MichalM. Please, do not add duplicate text only to match the requirement of having more description when adding too much code. Please, consider removing the unnecessary code and focusing only on the part with problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex in the lambda for the [UnaryOperator text change filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#getFilter--) that you have defined on the text formatter for your text field is preventing the text field from being set to an empty value.

From the javadoc:

> The filter itself is an `UnaryOperator` that accepts `TextFormatter.Change` object. It should return a `TextFormatter.Change` object that contains the actual (filtered) change. Returning null rejects the change.

You define your formatter filter to require a match of `"^\\d{1,2}"`, which isn't going to match an empty string `""`, so it will disallow setting the text field to an empty string:

```
text.setTextFormatter (new TextFormatter<Integer>(c -> {
    if (c.getControlNewText().matches("^\\d{1,2}")) {
        return c ;
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
}));
```

You need to fix the regular expression for the match to allow an empty string or provide some other fix which will allow an empty string value in the field.  For example:

```
text.setTextFormatter (new TextFormatter<Integer>(c -> {
    String newText = c.getControlNewText();
    if ("".equals(newText) || newText.matches("^\\d{1,2}")) {
        return c ;
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
}));
```